# .NET Code System.Web install source

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.web

Using Visual Studio Code on my mac book on sort of a Hello World type app.  However, when I try to include a reference to System.Web, I get an alert stating:

> The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [netcoreapp1.0]
>   Unnecessary using directive. [netcoreapp1.0]

I obviously supposed to add a reference System.Web, but giving the relative newness of this, I'm not sure of which nuget package I should apply to the project.

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: From menu : Project : Add Reference : .Net : Add Component 'System'.  The WEB is in the System library.  Also make sure you have 'using System'.

Comment: @jdweng unless this guy is doing Mono, there would be no System.Web at all. Read the question carefully.

Comment: You are not "supposed to add a reference System.Web". Forget about it and carefully study the new ASP.NET Core, https://docs.asp.net, which is 100% "System.Web" free. If you come from old ASP.NET, start with https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Removed System.Web dependence is one of the benefit of ASP.NET Core, that by the way allows to build and run cross-platform ASP.NET apps. From [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html):

> ASP.NET Core has a number of architectural changes that result in a much leaner and modular framework. ASP.NET Core is no longer based on System.Web.dll. It is based on a set of granular and well factored NuGet packages.

Don't know about source with nuget package descriptions, but you can start from searching in https://github.com/aspnet for appropriate project